# How to reverse transition?

Tags: css, transition

I have a transition from height:0, width:0 to a certain width. It is working fine, from the bottom left to the top right. Now I thought if I change the float to 'right', the transition would go from bottom right to top left. Is there some way to make this transition?

css:

```
.ablauftext{
    height:0;
    width:0;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:white;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;    
    bottom:90px;
}

.active{
    height:400px;
    width:400px;    
}
```

javascript:

```
$('#planung').click(function(){
    if(!$current.is('#planungtext')){
        $($current).removeClass('active');
        setTimeout(function(){$('#planungtext').addClass('active')}, 1000);
        $current = $('#planungtext');
    }
});
```

I have IDs on my elements with only the floats, so I don't think I have to add this CSS here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now, I simply had to add a the right position, like so:

```
.yourdiv{
   right:anyamount;
}
```